# jQuery validation plugin submits even if validation errors occur

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, submit

I am trying to validate a bootstrap form with jQuery.

```
  var formSubmit =  $("#dl-mg-form-publish").validate({
        rules: {
            'dl-mg-input-youtube': {
                required: true,
                url:true,
            },
            'dl-mg-input-title': {
                required: true,
                minlength: 6   });
```

I am trying to validate this:

```
 var videoInformation = {
        youtubeID: $('#dl-mg-input-youtube').val(),
        title: $('#dl-mg-input-title').val(), }
```

This is my html:

```
  <form class="form-horizontal dl-mg-form-horizontal" id="dl-mg-form-publish"  action="#">


    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="dl-mg-input-youtube" class="control-label col-xs-2">YouTube Video ID:</label>

        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <input type="url" class="form-control" id="dl-mg-input-youtube" name="dl-mg-input-youtube" placeholder="Youtube ID">

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="dl-mg-input-title" class="control-label col-xs-2">Video Title:</label>

        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dl-mg-input-title" name="dl-mg-input-title" placeholder="Video Title">

        </div>
    </div>
```

I am new at programming I don't know how to validate first and then submit. I tried using a .click handler but it submits the fields with errors anyway. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before submitting your form you need to validate the form. You can do this inside the `click` event like:

```
$("#target").click(function () {

    // Validate the form first
    if (!$("#dl-mg-form-publish").valid()) return false;

    // Your form is valid, so continue with you submit logic..
});
```

More info here: [.valid()](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/)

**EDIT:**

*Disable auto validation on keypress*

Use this options for the `validate()` method:

```
$("#dl-mg-form-publish").validate({
     onfocusout: false,
     onkeyup: false,
     // other options here
})
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! Do you know how to disable the automatic error, like, when I start writing it says automatically "Please enter at least 6 characters." after the first letter I type. I want this to be displayed only when I click the button. Any ideas?

Comment: @Shirohige yup, it's very easy just use the above option that I have mentioned in the updated code. Hope it helps! **P.S.** Please do mark the [answer as accepted](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5235) to help other users too.

Comment: Thanks! You're the best ^^can I choose your answer as best answer or something? Sorry I'm new here